# PHP openssl_encrypt and openssl_decrypt aes-256-gcm not work if inside function

Tags: php, openssl

I'm doing test with php openssl_encrypt and openssl_decrypt in a simple script without having the 2 inside any function but as soon I put the openssl_encrypt one inside a custom function that it's not working and there's no clear error string returns. Just have no clue what's the issue. I've attached the sample.

So if I comment out openssl_encrypt line and use encrypt() then it's not working but if put back openssl_encrypt then it works again. Any idea what's the issue when I use encrypt()?

```
$algo = 'aes-256-gcm';
$options = 0;
$iv = openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(openssl_cipher_iv_length($algo));
$key  = '13123123123';
$data = 'test';
$tag = null;
//$ciphertext = openssl_encrypt($data, $algo, $key, $options, $iv, $tag);
$ciphertext = encrypt($data, $algo, $key, $options, $iv, $tag);
$decrypt = openssl_decrypt($ciphertext, $algo, $key, $options , $iv, $tag);
if (false === $decrypt) {
    echo sprintf("OpenSSL error: %s", openssl_error_string()."\n");
}
echo "data:$data\n";
echo "decrypt:$decrypt\n";
printf ("Decryption %s\n", $data === $decrypt ? 'Ok' : 'Failed');

function encrypt($data, $algo, $key, $options, $iv, $tag) {
    return openssl_encrypt($data, $algo, $key, $options, $iv, $tag);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In the function signature of [`openssl_encrypt`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.openssl-encrypt.php) you see that `$tag` is passed as a **reference** (`&$tag`), but you dont do it.

The following works:

```
function encrypt($data, $algo, $key, $options, $iv, &$tag) {
    return openssl_encrypt($data, $algo, $key, $options, $iv, $tag);
}
```

Comment: Hey Code Spirit, it seems I got an issue. So I put the encrypt/decrypt function into a class and I encrypt something then save it on db then another separate session calls to decrypt with data from db but the decrypt return false. But it works if I run encrypt/decrypt together on the same run. I wonder if there's issue with the way tag is passed as reference to both. So if I have them called in separate run the tag data is no longer the same one even it has the same string. Have you used within a class and calls the openssl_encrypt and openssl_decrypt separately?

Answer (score 0):

```php
$random_key= openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(16);
$iv=bin2hex($random_key);
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).